# How to connect to Mongodb reliably in a serverless setup?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, serverless, vercel

8 out of ten times everything connects well. That said, I sometimes get a `MongoClient must be connected before calling MongoClient.prototype.db` error. How should I change my code so it works reliably (100%)?

I tried a code snippet from one of the creators of the Now Zeit platform.

My handler

```
const { send } = require('micro');
const { handleErrors } = require('../../../lib/errors');
const cors = require('../../../lib/cors')();
const qs = require('micro-query');
const mongo = require('../../../lib/mongo');
const { ObjectId } = require('mongodb');

const handler = async (req, res) => {
  let { limit = 5 } = qs(req);

  limit = parseInt(limit);
  limit = limit > 10 ? 10 : limit;

  const db = await mongo();

  const games = await db
    .collection('games_v3')
    .aggregate([
      {
        $match: {
          removed: { $ne: true }
        }
      },
      { $sample: { size: limit } }
    ])
    .toArray();

  send(res, 200, games);
};

module.exports = handleErrors(cors(handler));
```

My mongo script that reuses the connection in case the lambda is still warm:

```
// Based on: https://spectrum.chat/zeit/now/now-2-0-connect-to-database-on-every-function-invocation~e25b9e64-6271-4e15-822a-ddde047fa43d?m=MTU0NDkxODA3NDExMg==
const MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;

if (!process.env.MONGODB_URI) {
  throw new Error('Missing env MONGODB_URI');
}

let client = null;

module.exports = function getDb(fn) {
  if (client && !client.isConnected) {
    client = null;
    console.log('[mongo] client discard');
  }

  if (client === null) {
    client = new MongoClient(process.env.MONGODB_URI, {
      useNewUrlParser: true
    });
    console.log('[mongo] client init');
  } else if (client.isConnected) {
    console.log('[mongo] client connected, quick return');
    return client.db(process.env.MONGO_DB_NAME);
  }

  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    client.connect(err => {
      if (err) {
        client = null;
        console.error('[mongo] client err', err);
        return reject(err);
      }

      console.log('[mongo] connected');
      resolve(client.db(process.env.MONGO_DB_NAME));
    });
  });
};
```

I need my handler to be 100% reliable.

Comment: It might be that your Lambda is executed "too many" times concurrently and your DB server does not support that many opened parallel connections. Can you check its configuration? You can limit concurrency on the Lambda level as well https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/concurrent-executions.html#per-function-concurrency

Answer (score 1):

```
  if (client && !client.isConnected) {
    client = null;
    console.log('[mongo] client discard');
  }
```

This code can cause problems! Even though you're setting `client` to `null`, that client still exists, will continue connecting to mongo, will *not* be garbage collected, and **its callback connection code will still run, but in its callback `client` will refer to the next client that's created that is not necessarily connected**.

A common pattern for this kind of code is to only ever return a single promise from the `getDB` call:

```js
let clientP = null;
function getDb(fn) {
  if (clientP) return clientP;
  clientP = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    client = new MongoClient(process.env.MONGODB_URI, {
      useNewUrlParser: true
    });
    client.connect(err => {
      if (err) {
        console.error('[mongo] client err', err);
        return reject(err);
      }

      console.log('[mongo] connected');
      resolve(client.db(process.env.MONGO_DB_NAME));
    });
  });
  return clientP;
};
```

Comment: That's a good point. Are you saying that you don't think you need to worry about a client that isn't connected (because it will try to connect again on its own?) Your replacement code wouldn't handle this situation. I've had to significantly increase the connection retry count as by default the client gives up after 30 seconds of retrying.

Comment: There are a ton of options for connection settings to make sure that you're able to connect (and reconnect on loss of connection) -- http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/core/driver/reference/connecting/connection-settings/

Comment: Are you worried about losing connections or about failing to create the initial connection? You shouldn't ever need to create more than a single MongoClient

Comment: More about losing the connection. But you're right, the right solution should be to increase the connection retry options.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. In my case it was caused by calling getDb() before a previous getDb() call had returned. In this case, I believe that 'client.isConnected' returns true, even though it is still connecting.

This was caused by forgetting to put an 'await' before the getDb() call in one location. I tracked down which by outputting a callstack from getDb using:

```
console.log(new Error().stack);
```

I don't see the same issue in the sample code in the question, though it could be triggered by another bit of code that isn't shown.

Answer (score 0):

I have written this article talking about serverless, lambda e db connections. There are some good concepts which could help you to find the root cause of your problem. There are also example and use cases of how to mitigate connection pool issues.

Just by looking your code I can tell it is missing this:

```
context.callbackWaitsForEmptyEventLoop = false;
```

[Serverless: Dynamodb x Mongodb x Aurora serverless](https://medium.com/@cbernardes/serverless-things-i-wish-i-had-known-part-2-dynamodb-x-mongodb-x-aurora-serverless-1053cfddff36)